# Design Issue in Stack Exchange App

Tags: bug, android-app

I installed Stack Exchange App but I couldn't use it effectively. The questions/answers are almost covered with black backgrounds/overlays.

I've included the screenshots below.

Does anybody else face this issue? Have you tried fixing it? Please somebody help me get it fixed. Or is it a bug in the app. I'm posting this because I couldn't find a **Report Bug** feature within the app.

Platform: Android 4.0

App Name: Stack Exchange Android App

Version: 1.0.5

And it says "**Beta Version**". I think the issue is because it's still in development.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yup, sure looks like it might be an issue :P

Comment: @Undo Yeah. Even I tried clearing the cache, restarted the app & mobile. Still the same. So how do I report this? Only through Google Play? Any other option?

Comment: @Rocky You're in the right place to report this.

Comment: What version of the application are you using? What device? (You can find the version by hitting the overflow button in the actionbar and selecting Help)

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Updated the question with app version.

Comment: @Rocky This issue was resolved in 1.0.6. The newest version is 1.0.11, please update to it.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Thank You. I'll try updating it and see if I still have the issue.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi Yeah. You're right. It's fixed after updating to the latest version. Yet there's a problem in viewing the code within the question/answers. If the code is at the top, only the background is visible. I'll have to drag a bit and hold to see the code inside. I guess it'll be fixed in the next version.